# Rename [lens] to [haskell-lens]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[lens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lens)

> A lenses library for Haskell.

This is confusing some users. There's also [lenses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lenses)

> In functional programming, a lens is a composable field accessor. Lenses allow nested data structures to be manipulated in a concise and side-effect-free way.

A quick [look at the questions not tagged Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blens%5D+-%5Bhaskell%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0) reveals more than a few that are confusing the two. Since [lens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lens) specifically says it's for Haskell, and most questions are tagged that way, a rename and synonym seems appropriate.

Comment: Hmmm.... **needs *focus*** ☺

Comment: *and most questions are tagged that way* - a *rename* operation is fairly blunt - how many aren't tagged that way?

Comment: @JonClements Per my link above, 27 are not tagged [haskell]

Comment: Maybe rename the generic one to `functional-lenses`/`functional-lens` as well to avoid people still tagging `haskell` + `lenses`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through the [lens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lens) tag, and there were 18 questions that weren't related to the Haskell lenses library. 9 of them were about [lenses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lenses), therefore I retagged them with [lenses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lenses). The remaining were a mixture of using phone camera lens, Open CV detection of lenses, lens distortion, and others. I just removed the tag from them.

After that there were 388 posts which were all tagged with [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell), so I renamed the tag as [haskell-lens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-lens). I did not create a synonym for this as [lens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lens) is quite generic and might be mistagged.

For now, [lens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lens) is gone, the next step is to clean up the [14 seemingly unrelated questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+%5Blenses%5D+is%3Aq+-%5Bfunctional-programming%5D+-%5Bhaskell%5D+-%5Bscala%5D+-%5Bscalaz%5D+-%5Bpurescript%5D+-%5Bramda.js%5D+-%5Belm%5D+-%5Bprolog%5D+-%5Bocaml%5D&mixed=0) with the tag [lenses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lenses).